# Ruby - Boolean evaluation in a lambda

Tags: ruby, lambda

I have the following code:

```
def conditional_map
  ->(condition, if_true, if_false) { condition ? if_true : if_false }.curry
end
map = conditional_map.(->(object){ object.is_a?(Hash) }, ->(object) { object.inspect }, ->(object) { object.class })
map.(5)
```

I would expect the output to be Fixnum, but instead I'm getting object.inspect result. However, if I state boolean condition explicitly and make call like:

```
map = conditional_map.(5.is_a?(Hash), ->(object) { object.inspect }, ->(object) { object.class })
map.(5)
```

it works just fine. Any idea why is it like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
condition ? if_true : if_false
```

In above, `condition` is a proc, hence it is always truthy. when you define `map`, your proc from conditional_map is executed and returns a proc defined by `if_true` (since condition is satisfied). Hence when you execute your map, you will always get `inspect` method called. That's not the way to go.

```
conditional_map.(1,2,3) #=> 2, since 1 is true-like
```

Comment: Yeah, I got this. Probably, I asked incorrect question: why lambda `condition` is not evaluated? Sorry for stupid question, but just starting with ruby.

Comment: Because you didn't tell it to. The problem however is that even if you evaluate it, it will be called on the creation of the map, hence your `map` will always be one of the `if_true` or `if_false` procs, even before you pass any object.

Comment: I can't call in on the creation of the `map`, since I don't have the object yet to check if it is a Hash or not. Basically, I can't have a lambda which returns boolean and use it in `if` statement. Just because lambda is an object and not nil, therefore always true....

Comment: Yep, you're correct - you can't do this that way. You'll need to find another way. I wouldn't personally use `curry` for it, as it makes it incredible unreadable. Just define `conditional_map` as a normal method taking three arguments.